# T-SQL to CAML - I wonder what's missing in the CAML (T-SQL works)

Tags: sql, t-sql, caml

I have this SQL query and it works perfectly. However, when I try to create a similar CAML it doesn't work. Is there a tool that can convert SQL to CAML. or can someone please help me with proper CAML query. Here is the link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0557ef/10) .

```
select assignedto
from sample_approvers_list
where
libraryname='packaging' and level='a' and LineName = 'pure'
or
(libraryname='packaging' and level='a' and AnyLine='Yes')
```

[image]

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Library' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>Packaging</Value>
        </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Level' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
            </Eq>            
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='LineName' />
                    <Value Type='Lookup'>PURE</Value>
                </Eq>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyLine' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq> 
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyPlace' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>          
            </Or>           
        </And>
    </And>  
</Where>
```

Comment: Well the SQL compiles down to `where libraryname='packaging' and level='a' and (LineName = 'pure' or AnyLine='Yes')` whereas the CAML code is effectively `where libraryname='Packaging' and (level='A' or (LineName = 'PURE' and AnyLine= 1 and AnyPlace = 1)` so they're definitely not equivalent (upper/lowercase aside)

Comment: Can someone please suggest what should be the proper CAML query for the equivalent SQL query>?

Comment: Changed my mind: looks like it's actually `libraryname='Packaging' and level='A' and (LineName = 'PURE' or (AnyLine= 1 and AnyPlace = 1))`. No idea exactly what to do because I haven't the faintest idea what CAML is in the first place, just guessing based on the format of the above XML. But it doesn't look too difficult: just place the `<Or` node in its own `<And>` node

Answer (score 0):

Check if this CAML condition (WHERE section) solve your need:

```
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="LibraryName" />
            <Value Type="Text">Packaging</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="level" />
            <Value Type="Text">a</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Or>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="LineName" />
               <Value Type="Text">pure</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="AnyLine" />
               <Value Type="Text">Yes</Value>
            </Eq>
         </Or>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

The SQL query condition which it should solve is:

```
where libraryname='packaging' and level='a' and (LineName = 'pure' or AnyLine='Yes')
```

Notice that in your query there is always need for `libraryname='packaging' and level='a'` so we can use it once

Comment: Thanks for the CAML. However, I getting error for the CAML query. I change the type to lookup and choice and boolean. The execution returned an unexpected error.
Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.